# Angular 10 - can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am already having a running Angular application, as there is functionality extending I have to implement the routing and login page for the application. Previously routing is not there, as part of routing I have added the following code.

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        EditorModule,
        AngularEditorModule,
        NgxUiLoaderModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        LoginComponent,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { ReactiveFormsModule }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from '../app/app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'LoginComponent' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from '../app/app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'LoginComponent' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**login.component.html**

```html
<body>
    <div class="container col-lg-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="form-group" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="handleLogin()">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf='invalidLogin'>{{errorMessage}}</div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf='loginSuccess'>{{successMessage}}</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">User Name :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" id="username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && l.username.errors }" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && l.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="l.username.errors.required">User Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" id="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && l.password.errors }" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && l.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="l.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-success">
                            <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                            Login
                        </button>
                        <a routerLink="/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**login.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    errorMessage = 'Invalid Credentials';
    successMessage: string;
    invalidLogin = false;
    loginSuccess = false;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });
     }
     get l() {
         return this.loginForm.controls;
     }

     handleLogin() {
         debugger;
         this.submitted = true;

         // stop here if form is invalid
         if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
             return;
         }

         this.loading = true;
         this.authenticationService.authenticationService(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((result) => {
             debugger;
             this.loading = false;
             if (result) {
                 this.router.navigate(['/home']);
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

When I tried to execute with `ng-serve` I am getting the following error:

```
 ERROR in src / app / login / login.component.html: 6: 34 - error NG8002: Can 't bind to '
 formGroup ' since it isn'
 t a known property of 'form'.

 6 < form class = "form-group" [formGroup] = "loginForm"(ngSubmit) = "handleLogin()" >
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     src / app / login / login.component.ts: 7: 16
 7 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
 src / app / login / login.component.html: 11: 94 - error NG8002: Can 't bind to '
 ngClass ' since it isn'
 t a known property of 'input'.

 11 < input type = "text"
 class = "form-control"
 formControlName = "username"
 id = "username" [ngClass] = "{ 'is-invalid': submitted && 
 l.username.errors
 }
 "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 src / app / login / login.component.ts: 7: 16
 7 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
 src / app / login / login.component.html: 19: 98 - error NG8002: Can 't bind to '
 ngClass ' since it isn'
 t a known property of 'input'.

 19 < input type = "password"
 class = "form-control"
 formControlName = "password"
 id = "password" [ngClass] = "{ 'is-invalid': submitted && l.password.errors }"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     src / app / login / login.component.ts: 7: 16
 7 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `FormsModule` from routing module?

Comment: @Jai I tried removing `FormsModule`, No change in the error

Comment: I suspect the `LoginComponent` is in a module other than the app module. I don't see it declared there. You will need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module were the `LoginComponent` is declared is to get this to work.

Comment: Put the code of `login.component.html` & `login.component.ts` for better understanding your problem or provide a sample of your project in Stackblitz

Comment: @ng-hobby I have updated the login related code

Comment: Ok, I'm checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `login.component.ts` there is no selector for component, It should be like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
 })
```

In addition in `app.module.ts`, put `LoginComponent` in the `declarations`. You put it in `imports` which is incorrect.

Comment: The errors are cleared now after declaring the Logincomponent in declarations, but routing is not working when I tried to enter /login

Comment: There is no error and the URL is not getting changed

Comment: if I enter `http://localhost:4200/` the url is not getting changed, it is just showing the content in the `login.component.html`

Comment: It's because in your `routing.Module you have` {path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },` which means default rout is login. if you want change to heme and if user is not login redirected to the login should change it to `home` and use `Guard`

Comment: Replace first route with this: `{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },`

Comment: I am saying the url is not going to /login

Comment: use this `{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }`

Comment: @ng-hobby thank u, u save my day

Answer (score 16):

The problem is you have not declared the `LoginComponent` in `app.module.ts`

just declare the `LoginComponent` in `declarations`

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent==> Add this!
  ]
```

Comment: yeah all the errors are cleared but the routing is not working, if I enter /login it is not redirecting

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Realized just now that angular cli commands doesn't add this automatically. wtf

Comment: Thank you, well that isn't obvious from the error message is it!

Comment: Thank you this worked for me !, I had nested module created and was causing issue in that. but after register component fixed my compilation error

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from `LoginComponent`.
Can we see your module / component of `LoginComponent` ?
I suspect you forgot to implement `FormsModule` and `CommonModule` in there.

It can also come from the way you made LoginComponent.
Create a `login.module.ts`, add `LoginComponent` in declaration and exports.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone runs into the same problem I had - which was that, I had created the login component within the Core Module (core.module.ts) per Angular Style guide, and I had forgotten to (or Angular-CLI neglected to) include it in the apps.module.ts.

This was one of many symptoms of that problem, other being: Can't bind 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Once I put the Core Module within the App Module, the problem went away.  The issue helping to resolve is also whether the problem is being thrown via IVY (compiler) or via VSCode (TypeScript).  For me, I was able to solve many TypeScript problems via StackOverflow, but it failed to compile in IVY.

Answer (score 0):

in your login.component.ts file, change

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    -------> This

TO

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

After that, If your Login Component is a module or inside a module aside from the app.module project tree. You will need to import ReactiveFormsModule inside the module.